# PHP and AJAX - mkdir issue

Tags: php, ajax, mkdir

I am working on an intranet application that uses PHP and jQuery. When a user submits a form, the form is passed to another script via AJAX.

On one such form the user supplies a Windows UNC path to a server on the network. The handler script needs to create the directory the user specifies so that files can be moved via another process.

If I run a script from the web server using `mkdir('\\server\path1\newpath')` it works just fine. So I know the web server user has correct access rights.

But when I use the exact same command to the same network server in a script called via AJAX it fails with "No such file or directory".

Does the application lose its identity in an ajax call? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are they both being run as the same user (so that they have the same permissions)?

Comment: Are the slashes in the path being interpreted as escape sequences?..

Comment: If the script is actually mkdir('\server\path1\newpath') then the slashes shouldn't be interpreted as escape characters. single quote doesn't interpolate

Comment: Same user for both scripts.

The slashes did not come out correctly when I made the post. I have used addslashes and did a str_replace to reverse the slashes. Both methods work on the standalone script, but not on the ajax called script.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer - one of those "oh!" moments. The user form field had a space at the beginning of it (it is populated from a database field). A simple trim fixed that issue.

Thanks for reading the question, and apologies for my aging eyes.

Answer (score 0):

I had no idea backslashes can be this hard to deal with.  Your choices are

1. Make users enter an alternate directory seperator and use str_replace on the php side.
2. Ask users to enter 2 backslashes and the directory seperator and then use escape when posting, when it reaches php it will be the correct seperator of one backslash.

   submitForm = function(path)
   {
       $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'your_script.php',
           data: {path: escape(path)},
           success: function() { }
       });
   }

   submitForm('[2 backslashes]ugly[2 backslashes]windows[2 backslashes]path')

Not suprisingly the backslashes are preventing me from using the code formatting in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you will need to escape the path value with encodeURIComponent(). On the PHP side you will need to decode it with rawurldecode(). This will eliminate backslash issues for sure.

> Does the application lose its identity in an ajax call? Any ideas?

Under normal condition - no. It should preserve session. But if you manipulate cookies somehow - make sure you don't overwrite session id cookie.